# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server not working and showing yellow mark

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, visual-studio-2022, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

Trying to add the below package in the PWA application and it always showing yellow mark. Tried closing reopening Visual Studio, tried removing the bid and obj folder, still same error. it is net version 8.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server -Version 8.0.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i did some internet surf and found the common move in this situation may be you have tries these already , but i am providing them because these could be useful for other .

1.Check Compatibility: Verify that the version of the package you are trying to install is compatible with the .NET version being used in your PWA application. You can refer to the package documentation or release notes for compatibility information.

2.Update .NET Version: If the package version is not compatible with your current .NET version, consider updating your .NET version to a compatible one. This can be done by modifying the project file or using the .NET CLI.

2.Resolve Dependencies: Ensure that all the dependencies required by the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server package are installed and compatible with your project. You can check the package documentation or use the NuGet Package Manager to manage dependencies.

3.Clear NuGet Cache: Sometimes, issues with package installation can be resolved by clearing the NuGet cache. You can do this by going to the NuGet Package Manager settings and clearing the cache.

4.Check Network Connectivity: Ensure that your network connection is stable and not blocking the package download. You can try disabling any firewall or antivirus software temporarily to see if it resolves the issue.

**to prevent these from happening i will recommend to all that Before proceeding with the installation of a new package, it is a good practice to test it in a separate project or environment to identify any potential issues beforehand.**